# graph api notifications returns empty data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

im building a facebook app and i want to notify the user

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

im using facebook php sdk

what i do:

user auths the app and accepts permission

i get the accesstoken like:

```
$facebook->getAccessToken()
```

and then i generate a long-time token like:

```
public function generateLongTimeToken($token){
    $long_time_token_req_body = array(
        "grant_type"=>"fb_exchange_token",
        "client_id"=>$this->facebookOptions["appId"],
        "client_secret"=>$this->facebookOptions["secret"],
        "fb_exchange_token"=>$token
    );
    $query = http_build_query($long_time_token_req_body);
    $lttreq = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?".$query);
    $lttresp = parse_str($lttreq, $output);
    if ( array_key_exists("access_token", $output)){
        $this->logger->info("Facebook-app: Successfuly generated long_time_token");
        return $output["access_token"];      
    }else {
        $this->logger->err("Facebook-app: generating oauth long_time_token failed \n".$lttreq);
        return false;
    }
}
```

some later i use this token for background processes to post on the users wall and them all work fine

now i also want to notificate the user like that :

```
public function notifyUser($message,$facebookClientId,$token){
    $appsecret_proof= hash_hmac('sha256', $token, $this->facebookOptions["secret"]); 

    $req_body = array(
        "access_token"=>$token,
        "appsecret_proof"=>$appsecret_proof,
        "href"=>"/index",
        "template"=>$message,
        "ref"=>"post"
    );

    $query = http_build_query($req_body);

    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$facebookClientId."/notifications?".$query;

    $lttreq = file_get_contents($url);


    return $lttreq;


}
```

but when i try to notify the user i always get empty data back
when i open the url in browser with all parameters facebook returns  the same

```
{  
  data: [ ]
}
```

so i have no idea whats going on,when i look on SO i only find about people posting to sites but i want to notify the user itself

thanks for any help

Comment: is your app a canvas app?

Comment: @luschn at the moment its running locally on an apache server, its in development and has not been published or reviewed yet

Answer (score 1):

First, from the Facebook docs:

> Currently, only apps on Facebook.com can use App Notifications.
>   Notifications are only surfaced on the desktop version of
>   Facebook.com.

Also, an App Token is needed, not a User Token.

Btw, file_get_contents is very bad, use CURL for Facebook. May be another reason why it does not work. A basic example of using CURL with the Facebook API: http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Additional Info: I recently wrote a blogpost about App Notifications, it is in german but the small code part may be interesting for you: http://blog.limesoda.com/2014/08/app-notifications-facebook-apps/

Comment: so this means it also wont work with a canvas app ? or are them "on facebook.com" as the host of the canvas url is my host?

Comment: it will work with a canvas app > apps.facebook.com/namespace > it is on facebook.com

Comment: dont forget to use an app token, not a user token. would be my main tip.

Comment: i have added some more information, i hope it helps

Comment: alright, nevertheless i dont understand why i can post to the wall with the same method i want to use for notifications

Comment: oh no i mean i use the same long-time user token and the appsecret_proof and it works

Comment: you really should use an app token for notifications. no need for any extended user token then, and it will work as long as the user did not deauthorize.